# Data clean up: are there libraries of common permutations that we can use? Or is there a better approach?

Tags: nlp, match

We are working on clean-up and analysis of a lot of human-entered customer data. We need to decide programmatically whether 2 addresses (for example) are the same, even though the data was entered with slight variations.

Right now we run each address through fairly simplistic string replacement (replacing avenue with ave, for example), concatenate the fields and compare the results. We are doing something similar with names.

At the very least, it seems like our list of search-replace values should already exist somewhere.

Or perhaps you can suggest a totally different and superior way to detect matches?

Answer (score 3):

For the addresses, you should run them through google's map api and get a geocode for each one.  Then if the geocodes are the same, the place is the same.  I believe they allow 10k hits/day/ip for free.

It's unlikely that you'd come up with anything better on your own.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

Comment: Careful - Google won't always return CORRECT results, it only makes a best-guess.

Answer (score 1):

[Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) and its variants might be a good start as are other approaches suggested by that Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you're trying to find how similar two strings are and there are a lot of different ways to measure it. Dice Coefficients could work fairly well for what you're doing, although it is a bit costly of an operation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_coefficient

If you want a more comprehensive list of string similarity measures try here:
http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html

Comment: perhaps i'm missing something, but aren't "234 5th avenue, 2nd floor, new york NY 10002" and "234 7th avenue, 2nd floor, new york NY 10002" very similar strings but distinct addresses?

Answer (score 0):

At work I help write software that verifies addresses (for SmartyStreets).

Address validation is a really tricky operation -- in fact the USPS has designated certain companies which are certified to provide this service. I would not recommend (even if I was in your shoes) that you attempt this on your own. As mentioned, Google does some address parsing, but only *approximates* the address. Google and Yahoo and similar services will *not* verify the accuracy of the address data.

So you'll need a CASS-Certified approach to this problem. I would suggest something like the [LiveAddress API (for point-of-entry validation)](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/) or [Certified Scrubbing (for existing lists or databases of addresses)](https://www.smartystreets.com/Products/CASS-Certified-Scrubbing/). Both are CASS-Certified by the USPS and will do what you require.